# Activate/deactivate unique images (icons) instead of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I am trying to replace checkboxes with icons which will change opacity when selected.

Initially, all images should have low opacity.  When clicked, the clicked image should change to full opacity. If clicked again, the image should return to low opacity.

In the final version I will add `display:none` to the input elements so that the actual checkboxes will not display.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".img-checkbox").click(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  if (img.prev().checked) {
    img.css('opacity', '0.3');
  } else {
    img.css('opacity', '1.0');
  }
})
```

```css
.img-checkbox {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="pool">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="pets allowed">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="elevator">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="wifi">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not using jQuery (or javascript) at all.  Here I've hidden the checkboxes as you suggest you'll do in your final pass.

```css
/* image checkbox buttons */
.img-checkbox {
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
:checked+.img-checkbox {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Extra assumed classes */
.checkbox > label > input[type=checkbox]
{
  display:none;
}
.checkbox-inline, .checkbox
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">   
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="pool"><img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="pets allowed"><img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="elevator"><img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="wifi"><img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox"></label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert McKee -- I definitely prefer the css-only solution!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Robert McKee, JavaScript is not necessary here and could be avoided in favor of a simple CSS solution. However, you may be interested in learning JavaScript (or jQuery in particular) or other functionality you've not shown may rely on it.

In that case, I suggest binding the event listener to the inputs themselves rather than the images. In my example below, when a checkbox changes state, the relevant image is defined as the [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) image element after the clicked checkbox.

I've avoided using jQuery to reference the checked state because doing so in pure JavaScript is relatively simple ([`this.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/checked)) and I find it slightly more readable than the jQuery equivalent.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function() {
  var $img = jQuery(this).next('img');
  if (this.checked) {
    $img.css('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    $img.css('opacity', '0.3');
  }
})
```

To shorten the code, I've used a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to set the opacity based on the checked state:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).next('img').css('opacity', this.checked ? '1.0' : '0.3');
})
```

Demonstration below:

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).next('img').css('opacity', this.checked ? '1.0' : '0.3');
});
```

```css
.img-checkbox {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="pool">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="pets allowed">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="elevator">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="qRequirements" value="wifi">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" class="img-responsive img-checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions about jQuery.  I will keep this in mind for cases when css-only is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you're not grabbing the checked attribute in a way that works in jquery. 
[I made a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w067Ltp4/) with a better solution to your own code and why that isn't working.

However a different answer may be more efficient.

```
$(".img-checkbox").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);

   if (img.prev().prop("checked")) {
        img.css({
            'opacity': '0.3'
        });
    } else {
        img.css({
            'opacity': '1.0'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops, left an alert in the JSfiddle from debugging why yours wasn't triggering.

Comment: Thanks!  I see that I should have used .prop('checked') instead of .checked